# General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

I have the below sql query, but when i am trying to run the query it throws an error with no 1111, please some body help.

```
select count( distinct id_student) count, 
CASE 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()) THEN 'Subscription Expired' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) = sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Test Completed' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) < sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Active' 
END status 
from `order` 
inner join `student` on `id_student` = `order`.`student_id_student` 
inner join `order_has_test` on `order_id_order` = `order`.`id_order` 
inner join `subscription_plan` on `id_subscription_plan` = `subscription_plan_id_subscription_plan` 
where `subscription_plan_id_subscription_plan` = 1 
group by `order`.`student_id_student`, 
CASE 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()) THEN 'Subscription Expired' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) = sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Test Completed' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) < sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Active' 
END
```

Comment: Try changing your group by clause to `group by order.student_id_student, status` or better just `group by status`

Comment: Hi Matteo I already tried with the above criteria, but its not working. Every time i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and trying with some test cases finally i got the solution.

```
Select count(count) count,status from (select count(id_student) count, 
CASE 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()) THEN 'Subscription Expired' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) = sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Test Completed' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) < sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Active' 
END status 
from `order` 
inner join `student` on `id_student` = `order`.`student_id_student` 
inner join `order_has_test` on `order_id_order` = `order`.`id_order` 
inner join `subscription_plan` on `id_subscription_plan` = `subscription_plan_id_subscription_plan` 
where `subscription_plan_id_subscription_plan` = 1 
group by `order`.`student_id_student`) data
group by status
```

Answer (score 0):

The group by should contain only the case

```
select count(distinct id_student) count, 
CASE 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()) THEN 'Subscription Expired' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) = sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Test Completed' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) < sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Active' 
END status 
from `order` 
inner join `student` on `id_student` = `order`.`student_id_student` 
inner join `order_has_test` on `order_id_order` = `order`.`id_order` 
inner join `subscription_plan` on `id_subscription_plan` = `subscription_plan_id_subscription_plan` 
where `subscription_plan_id_subscription_plan` = 1 
group by
CASE 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE()) THEN 'Subscription Expired' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) = sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Test Completed' 
    WHEN (date_format(max(expiry_date),'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE() && sum(completed_test_count) < sum(total_test_count) ) THEN 'Active' 
END
```

Comment: and delete the space before the distinct

Comment: you have problem with your where you have field with that name"subscription_plan_id_subscription_plan"?